# Wrong EXE Application Icon with Resource files

Tags: delphi, resources, icons

I am exploring with (.Res) resource file and found a useful tutorial on delphi.about.com site.

Tutorial Link:
http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa113099a.htm

Download test project:
http://delphi.about.com/library/aboutres.zip

I found out that the application icon is different in Windows explorer. The icon on Application form appears correctly (Refer to Image 2). The icon on Windows task bar appears correctly (refer to Image 3).

But The icon is wrong in Windows Explorer when i browse it (Refer to Image 1). It is not MAINICON from Res file.

Any idea what's wrong with it?
What do I need to configure to get the correct application icon with .EXE file?

- Delphi XE3 Environment
- Windows 7 Environment
- You can download the sample project from above link

Image No (1)

[image: EXE Application icon is wrong in Windows Explorer]

Image No (2)

[image: Application icon appears correctly on the task bar]

Image No (3)

[image: Application icon appears correctly on the form]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having no hint of which icon to display, the shell chooses the one with the lowest ID, or the first one that comes alphabetically. You have three icons in your executable: ICOFOLD, ICOOK and MAINICON. ICOFOLD is the one that is to be displayed in a shell folder.

The taskbar or the form icon are set by sending `WM_SETICON` messages once your program runs. Hence there's no guesswork there.

Comment: Thanks @Sertac. If i delete one icon (ICOFOLD) from resource file, it appears that the first one from alphabetically order which is ICOOK. Do you know how to set up to get correct icon? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sMah Sertac has explained it clearly. The VCL demands that you name the application icon MAINICON. Explorer uses the first icon that it finds. So you must make sure that the first icon is your app icon.

Comment: I achieve that by making sure that all my other icons have names that appear after MAINICON. If you don't want to do that you can just include your app icon twice. Once as MAINICON and once with an ID of 1, say, or a name that is alphabetically before all others.

Comment: @Sertac Do you know who imposes alphabetical ordering. My guess is that the Delphi linker does that and explorer just enumerates all icons and uses the first. Would be odd for explorer to find all the names and pick the first. Perf reasons suggest picking first is quicker.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan for adding note. I thought there is another way to set the MAINICON. Now it is clear that I need to make sureMAINICON to be the first one. Thanks again.

Comment: @David - I don't know, I've never even thought about it actually. Your way of thinking make sense but in my experience I can't say explorer is really quick in this.

Answer (score 1):

The icon in the Taskbar and Form window are accurate, since they come directly from the resources of the running process.

Windows Explorer, on the other hand, [caches icons](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+explorer+icon+cache) and sometimes that cache gets corrupted or out-of-sync.  That is a well-known problem with Windows Explorer.  It has nothing to do with your app.  There are plenty of third-party tools available to repair the icon cache.

Comment: Hi @Remy Thanks for your reply. I run into that problem before. Thanks for your note about icon cache. I clear my icon cache. I think, for my specific case, It is not an icon cache issue. Thanks for your note.

Comment: @sMah, it is an icon cache issue, you have to rebuild it properly.

Comment: Hi @Peter, Thanks for your comment. I did clear the icon cache by deleting 
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\IconCache.db 
and I Log off and Log in to my PC. Then I recompiled it. The icon from window explorer has the same issue. (Wrong icon displayed)

Comment: @Peter - What do you suppose special about MAINICON, according to Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the following command to clear the icon cache:

`ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`

For Windows 10, use:

`ie4uinit.exe -show`